# How to calculate curvature of a 3 dimensional Bezier Curve?

Tags: linear-algebra, 3d, bezier-curve

The formula for curvature of a 2D bezier curve is as follows:

$κ(t)=\frac{|B′(t),B′′(t)|}{||B′(t)||^{3}}$

The dividend is the determinant of two joined vectors (2x2 where each vector is a column), but for 3D, the matrix would not be square, and therefore would have no determinant.
Is there a different equation for curvature of a 3D curve? Does one even exist?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! <> In two words, _yes_ and _yes_: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet%E2%80%93Serret_formulas.

Comment: Specifically, see the last-but-one formula in this section. It’s the same as the formula you cited, except that the numerator contains a cross product of two 3D vectors.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet-Serret_formulas#Other_expressions_of_the_frame